# How to hide grid's labels when zooming out?

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling, qgis-openlayers-plugin, vector-grid

I have used polygon grid layer on my map, and I used to label the layer with ID automatically, and the result was convenient for me:

[image]

But when I zoomed out, the labels didn't hide at all! and they keep appearing in frustrating way!

[image]

I would like to get the result when I zooming out like this:

[image]

What to do in this case to get this result?
How to hide grid's labels when I zooming out?

My vector grid is 1000 meter polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the layer's labels to be visible depending on desired scales, like below:

[image]

For a start, from what I've seen in your images, the label visibility may be set to visible between a minimum of 75000 and a maximum of 105000.

---

EDIT

As an alternative, if you think it is more convenient, you can use to have a label visibility based on the pixel size:

[image]